# List level pagination in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

Mongo document structure as follows:

```
{ 
    "dictID" : "dd001", 
    "dictVersion" : 1, 
    "addMeasures" : 
    [ 
        { 
            "measureId" : "f229ba18", 
            "userId" : "3966C3DD", 
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:22.512Z" 
        }, { 
            "measureId" : "0b701469", 
            "userId" : "3966C3DD", 
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:35.193Z" 
        } , { 
            "measureId" : "f229ba1823", 
            "userId" : "3966C3DD", 
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:22.512Z" 
        }, { 
            "measureId" : "0b7014699", 
            "userId" : "3966C3DD", 
            "created" : "2017-01-07T05:47:35.193Z" 
        } 
    ]
}
```

I need a pagination for single document on array list

Ex. In my document "addMeasures" has multiple maps, I want pagination on it so that it should give me part "addMeasures" like limit 1,2.

Answer (score 1):

use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator

```
db.collection.find({}, {dictId: 1, dictVersion: 1, addMeasures: {$slice: [0, 2]}})
```

returns:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("5890572371cbc5eae2c9535b"),
   "dictVersion":1,
   "addMeasures":[
      {
         "measureId":"f229ba18",
         "userId":"3966C3DD",
         "created":"2017-01-07T05:47:22.512Z"
      },
      {
         "measureId":"0b701469",
         "userId":"3966C3DD",
         "created":"2017-01-07T05:47:35.193Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: would like to add one can also use slice to get last 10 elements with $slice : -10.